# Cognito OAuth Integration

Tags: spring-boot, oauth-2.0, amazon-cognito

I have a spring boot application and I have to integrate user authentication flow with Cognito. Getting 401 for all requests. I couldnt figure out wht Iam getting 401 all the time. My audience could be wrong if it is wrong where I can get this information.

My Dependecies;

```
    <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-resource-server</artifactId>
        <version>5.6.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-jose</artifactId>
        <version>5.6.1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Application Yml is;

```
server:
  port: 9090

spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        provider:
          cognito:
            audience: **
            issuerUri: **
```

I got my audience from clientId;

[image: Audience]

And my Security Config Class;

```
@EnableWebFluxSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {
@Value("${spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.cognito.issuerUri}")
private String issuer;

@Value("${spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.cognito.audience}")
private String audience;

@Bean
SecurityWebFilterChain springSecurityFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) {
    http
            .authorizeExchange()
            .pathMatchers("/actuator/**").permitAll()
            .pathMatchers(GET, "/home").permitAll()
            .anyExchange().authenticated()
            .and()
            .cors()
            .and()
            .oauth2ResourceServer()
            .jwt()
            .jwtDecoder(jwtDecoder());

    return http.build();
}

ReactiveJwtDecoder jwtDecoder() {
    NimbusReactiveJwtDecoder jwtDecoder = (NimbusReactiveJwtDecoder)
            ReactiveJwtDecoders.fromOidcIssuerLocation(issuer);

    OAuth2TokenValidator<Jwt> audienceValidator = new AudienceValidator(audience);
    OAuth2TokenValidator<Jwt> withIssuer = JwtValidators.createDefaultWithIssuer(issuer);
    OAuth2TokenValidator<Jwt> withAudience = new DelegatingOAuth2TokenValidator<>(withIssuer, audienceValidator);

    jwtDecoder.setJwtValidator(withAudience);
    jwtDecoder.setClaimSetConverter(new ClaimAdapter());

    return jwtDecoder;
}}
```

Comment: It's unusual to use client properties to configure a resource server. Also, you could have a look at my tutorials, all work with Cognito (but I did not implement audience validation) https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials

Answer (score 0):

Cognito will set the audience of ID tokens to the client_id value. Cognito doesn't currently issue an audience claim to access tokens, so any resource server endpoints cannot validate the audience when using that authorization server. See [steps 11 and 12](https://authguidance.com/basicspa-oauthworkflow/) of my blog post for example tokens.